# How do I add a dimension to class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter' object in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a image data set that I want to use to train a CNN. I have initialized a class "tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter" object that I understand is essentially an iterator that caches the train images in batches so that the entire data set need not be loaded at once.

I have received this error when trying to call model.fit():

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with 
shape (None, 1)
```

I understand that I need to add a dimension to my model input. I want to add a channels dimension to my images. I have tried to use np.expand_dims() and tf.expand_dims() on my class "tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter" object but the former changes the object type and the latter is not supported for the class object. Any help is appreciated. Below is my model structure:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))


model.summary()

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
history = model.fit(train_data, epochs=10, validation_data=(val_data),steps_per_epoch=x, 
validation_steps=y)
```

I have been following the tutorial in the example listed here, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images, but have tried to create and load in my own data set.

Below is my tf pipeline:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(image_count/BATCH_SIZE)

data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\rtlum\\Documents\\DataSci_Projects\\PythonTensorFlowProjects\\google-images-download\\images'
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir+"*.jpg"))  #Make dataset of file paths
class_names = ['sad', 'angry']

size = 0
for count in enumerate(list_ds):
    size += 1
val_data_size = size * .2

for f in list_ds.take(5):#test for correct file paths
  print(f.numpy())

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  return parts[-2] == class_names

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # Use `convert_image_dtype` to convert to floats in the [0,1] range.
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
  # resize the image to the desired size.
  return tf.image.resize(img, [64, 64])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path)

for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())

shuffle_buffer_size=1000

def prepare_for_training(ds, cache=True, shuffle_buffer_size=1000):
  # This is a small dataset, only load it once, and keep it in memory.
  # use `.cache(filename)` to cache preprocessing work for datasets that don't
  # fit in memory.
  if cache:
    if isinstance(cache, str):
      ds = ds.cache(cache)
    else:
      ds = ds.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)
  # Repeat forever
  ds = ds.repeat()
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
  # `prefetch` lets the dataset fetch batches in the background while the model
  # is training.
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  return ds

ds = prepare_for_training(list_ds)


val_data = ds.take(int(val_data_size))
train_data = ds.skip(int(val_data_size))
```

Comment: Please share the code for your tf input pipeline.

Comment: I have edited my post to include my tf input pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems,

### Your wildcard for directory matching appears to be incorrect.

By looking at your code, it seems that your data needs to follow a structure like,

```
data
 |- sad
     |- 1.jpg
        ...
 |- angry
     |- 1.jpg
        ...
```

This is not what you're matching when you say,

`tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir+"*.jpg"))`

it should be,

`tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir+os.path.sep+"*"+os.path.sep+"*.jpg"))`

### You have the wrong dataset,

You have,

`ds = prepare_for_training(list_ds)`

should be,

`ds = prepare_for_training(labeled_ds)`

### Other issues,

- You are resizing data to 64x64, but your model accepts a 32x32 model.
- You have 2 labels, but your model expects 10 classes.
- You don't have a model compilation line (i.e. `model.compile(...)`)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am new to tensorflow and python. I changed the resizing of the images to 32x32, changed the last model layer to `layers.Dense(2)`, and corrected the improper directory string and wrong data set call. This seems to have resolved my original error. I did have a model.compile line, but just naively left it out of my question. I now have a new error that says `Cannot squeeze dim[1],.....`, but I think this is another error that I'll search for answers to.

Comment: All good. Feel free to create a new question with your error. The initial error was because, your `ds` was empty (as it had the wrong directory pattern). This is why your `ds` has shape `(None, 1)`